# How to specify a namespace or postfix on uwsgi?

Tags: python, uwsgi, fabric

I currently run this command to start uwsgi

`uwsgi --http :5000 --wsgi-file serviceapi/service_api.py --callable wsgi_app`

which runs an API on `localhost:5000`.

But I would like to run this API on `localhost:5000/api` instead. How can I do that?

I looking for an option from the `uwsgi --help` output but can't find out how.

Comment: did this work for you?  Are you using Django?  If so, can you post the code that you used?  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You have to use "mountpoints"

https://github.com/unbit/uwsgi-docs/blob/master/Snippets.rst#multiple-flask-apps-in-different-mountpoints

Comment: have you configured `mountpoints` for django?  I'd like to have one app run at: `example.com/one/` and one at `example.com/two/` for example. Ideally without using Nginx for the time being. Thank you.